# ilandroid wifi api to block uploading operation and allow only download

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, android-kernel

When WiFi is set to ON, is there a way to block outgoing data connection and allow only incoming data connection? Can it be controlled at framework level? If yes, can you please shed some light on this? I don't want to send data out and would be interested in receiving data only through my applications.

For ex: WhatsApp to receive incoming chats and to block outgoing chats.
Gmail to receive incoming emails and to block outgoing emails

Here the idea is to limit the data usage.

Any idea where in Android Framework stack, the above uses cases be differentiated as outgoing and incoming. Blocking those uses cases at application level is not preferred.

Note - I have rooted Android phone.

Comment: Can it be configured at system level to listen for incoming streams only?

Comment: Is there any listener available to catch those incoming messages at platform level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check whether it is connected to wifi or mobile data. you can change it to as you want

```
 /**
 * Method for checking internet connectivity
 */
public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context mContext) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) {
        // connected to the internet
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // connected to wifi
            return true;
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response... How the filtering be made for one way (sending data) alone here? Is there a way?

Comment: Can it be configured at system level to listen for incoming streams only?

Comment: you can check whether it is connected to wifi or mobile data. depends on that you can do the downloading.

Comment: This requirement is not specific to one single application... It is required to block all such huge data download operations pertaining to any XYZ application ( mail/chat/server sysnc and etc.,) ... Hence I am trying to locate the fix at core api part or system level... Hope you got it..